# How do these triplets code for these proteins?

Tags: genetics

[image]

I am slightly confused by the diagram above.

The first codon of the unaltered DNA is AAG. During transcription, isn't this coverted to UUC (mRNA). So doesn't UUC code for phe and not Lys?

Likewise, how does TAG code for a stop codon? Isn't it transcibed to AUC, which codes for ile?

Also, is that the coding strand or template strand? If there is a mutation in the coding strand, is there any impact on the protein?

[image]

Comment: translation is making protein out of mRNA. Transcription is making mRNA (UUC) out of DNA (AAG). TAG transcribes to UAG. Check wikipedia page for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(biology)

Comment: Isn't there complementary base parigng for the template strand? So won't AAG become UUC as A pairs with U and C pairs with G?

Comment: codons are defined by mRNA sequence, defined by gene sequence. Correspondence is 1:1 except Ts become Us. What materials you are using? Do you have access to some Cell Bio textbook?

Comment: @aaaaaa thanks so much for replying. I uploaded what my textbook said about transcription. When mRNA is formed from AAG, won't the mRNA have the code UUC due to complementary base pairing. That's what I'm believing as that is what my textbook says. So doesn't UUC code for a different amino acid, not Lys?

Comment: @ChristopherU'Ren you're correct: [transcription is complimentary](https://www.umass.edu/microbio/chime/dna/codons.htm). `ATGC` in DNA becomes `UACG` in RNA (except we think in terms of 3-base codons). What I think is confusing aaaaaa is that there are 2 strands of DNA: the coding strand and the template strand  (see [here](http://www.sci.sdsu.edu/~smaloy/MicrobialGenetics/topics/chroms-genes-prots/temp-strand.html) for explanation). The coding strand is the same as the mRNA (except for U vs T), but mRNA is actually transcribed from the *template* strand (which *is* complimentary to the mRNA).

Comment: @theforestecologist so is the first picture incorrect? Isn't AAG transcribed into UUC which codes for the amino acid Phe?

Comment: @ChristopherU'Ren it's not lysosomes, but "lysine." Also, no, AAG would be transcribed as UUC which is translated to Phenylalanine. See a [codon chart](https://www2.palomar.edu/users/warmstrong/images/codon1.gif) (source: [here](https://www2.palomar.edu/users/warmstrong/lmexer3.htm)).

Comment: However, if the book was showing you the *coding* strand of DNA (i.e., the strand *not* actually being used in transcription), then they're correct -- the coding strand triplet that is complimentary to the base triplet on the template strand used in transcription *is* going to be AAG when the resulting amino acid is lysine (and the codon in AAG). To summarize how the coding DNA strand, template DNA strand, and mRNA strand compare, see the [link](https://www.umass.edu/microbio/chime/dna/codons.htm) in my previous comment.

Comment: Note: In my experience, it's much less common for a textbook to show you the triplet on the coding strand (vs the template strand), but perhaps your book's authors/editors simply did not catch this mistake or preferred to illustrate this concept in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first image, AAG **is** the true codon for Lysine.  So when the ribosome hits "AAG" in the mRNA it recruits a Lysine-tRNA.

What can be confusing is the use of the term "coding strand" when talking about the DNA. The coding strand is illustrated in the second image you posted, and it is the coding strand of DNA that the first image is depicting. What "coding strand" means here is, this is the strand that *looks* like the mRNA will look. Depicting the DNA coding strand like this--i.e. as a series of codons--can be slightly misleading since we know codons really only *mean* anything when in the form of mRNA. Nevertheless, it is a common way of thinking about DNA.

Back to the first image. Because it is showing the "coding strand" of DNA, the "template strand" for 5'-AAG-3' then must be 5'-CTT-3'. Hence, when this strand is transcribed by RNA polymerase, the 5'-CTT-3'(DNA) becomes 5'-AAG-3'(mRNA).

Comment: Why does CTT become AAG? Isn't it GAA?

Comment: You need to always be thinking about this in terms of 5'-to-3'.  I indicted this above and I think that may be why you are getting confused.

Comment: Please provide support for your answer. Preferably, cite or link to reputable sources that back-up the claims you make. Thanks